# PHP If statement in html form

Tags: php, html, forms, if-statement

I have the following form but would like to add a condition so that only managers can see 'clear' option.

```
<form action="vision_ref.php" method="post">
    With selected: 
    <select name='multi'>
        <option value='now'>Set next action time to now</option>
        <option value='clear'>Remove the ticket</option>
        <option value='unassign'>Unassign Specialist</option>
        <option value='priority'>Toggle Priority</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

Something like: `if(havePriv('grp_mgr'))`

Comment: Is this a standalone HTML file, are you echo-ing it from a PHP file or are you using a templating engine?

Comment: btw, you have a very very low acceptance record on answers given

Comment: Thanks all, this is now working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if(havePriv('grp_mgr')) : ?>
    <option value='clear'>Remove the ticket</option>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Does the trick

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<form action="vision_ref.php" method="post">
    With selected: 
    <select name='multi'>
        <option value='now'>Set next action time to now</option>
        <?php  if(havePriv('grp_mgr')){ ?>
            <option value='clear'>Remove the ticket</option>
        <?php } ?>
        <option value='unassign'>Unassign Specialist</option>
        <option value='priority'>Toggle Priority</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

So "Remove the ticket" will only displayed if the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can say :

```
if(havePriv('grp_mgr'))
{
 echo "<option value='clear'>Remove the ticket</option>";
}
```